# ¿Cómo pasar cada posición de un string a un int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for

A partir de un *string*, que representa un *array* o *vector* de valores, por ejemplo: `a="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0"`, y se quiere ir comparando cada número de ese *string* con un número concreto.

Había pensado en utilizar un *bucle* `for i in range(0,len(a))` y dentro una sentencia `if-else`, pero no me devuelve nada, he intentado coger esa posición y convertirla primero en un `int` y comparar pero no lo consigo.

Os dejo lo que tengo, por si me podéis ayudar.

Nota: También lo he intentado con una lista y me sale lo que quiero hacer, pero ha de ser un array (string, no me sale).

Código cuando intento pasarlo a int:

```
 #!/usr/bin/pyhton3
def metodo(lista):
    contador = 0
    for i in range(0,len(lista)):
        a = int(lista[i])
        if a == 3:
            return contador
            break
        else:
            contador = contador+1
            i=i+1


def main():
    lista = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0"
    a = metodo(lista)
    print (a)

main()
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que tu cadena tiene espacios, que no son convertibles a `int`. Lo normal sería usar `str.split`:

```
#!/usr/bin/pyhton3
def metodo(lista):
    contador = 0
    for a in lista.split():
        if a == "3":
            return contador
        else:
            contador += 1


def main():
    lista = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0"
    a = metodo(lista)
    print(a)

main()
```

Algunas observaciones:

- Tal como planteas la lógica, no necesitas para nada convertir a `int`, compara con una cadena ("3") directamente. No obstante, si quisieras hacerlo simplemente:

  ```
   for a in lista.split():
       a = int(a)
  ```
- No necesitas usar `break` después de `return`, `return` ya causa que la función termine en ese punto y por tanto el ciclo también.
- Incrementar `i` en `i=i+1` tampoco sirve para nada porque en la siguiente iteración del `for` se le asigna el nuevo valor procedente del rango, ignorando totalmente tu incremento.
- En Python si solo vas a iterar sobre cualquier iterable con la finalidad de obtener sus items, no uses indizado y `range`, usa un `for in`. Es más eficiente y legible. El indizado es útil cuando se va a modificar el valor de ese item.

Parece que buscas la posición del primer 3 en la cadena (obviando los espacios). Si es así podrías usar `list.index` simplemente sobre la salida de `str.split`:

```
def metodo(lista):
    try:
        return lista.split().index("3")
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```